# No module named 'Kivy' even though I installed it

Tags: python, kivy, importerror

I've installed Kivy and all the need files as far as I know, but I'm still getting this error message and I don't know why.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Container(GridLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Awesome app!!!'
        return Container()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yassi\OneDrive\Afbeeldingen\Bureaublad\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named 'kivy'
```

I installed Kivy through anaconda, so the files for kivy might be installed in a wrong directory. Either way, I don't know how to fix this problem.

I'm running this program on a Windows 10 OS and I use python-3

**Edit: It might have something to do with how I refer to the python interpreter. I can't find the location of the python interpreter though so now I'm stuck.**

**Edit2: This is the place where I installed python: C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\25\Python3. Any way how I can refer to this? I think this is where the problem lies.**

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? Also you may want to activate your environment with source activate [name of env] or conda activate [name of env]

Comment: I entered conda activate base (the only environment in C:\Users\Yassi) and it didn't help. I also have Python 2.7 installed yes

Comment: there are so, so *so* many reasons a module might not be able to be imported, I can't even guess what it could be.

Comment: @Y.Ben Simply run CMD there with admin rights, and install traditionally kivy via pip, or totally reinstall python.

Comment: But everytime it installs the files on the same place so it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Check if in current enviroment you have kivy installed:

```
import pip._internal as pip

print([i.key for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
# or 
pip.main(['freeze'])
```

So you will see if in this enviroment you have kivy installed.
To make sure you have kivy installed in this enviroment you can write something like this:

```
try:
    from kivy.app import App
except ImportError:
    import pip._internal as pip
    pip.main(['install', 'kivy'])
    from kivy.app import App
```

Comment: This is the error message I get when I run your second piece of code

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yassi/OneDrive/Afbeeldingen/Bureaublad/ddd.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named 'kivy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yassi/OneDrive/Afbeeldingen/Bureaublad/ddd.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pip._internal as pip
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Comment: If `pip._internal` is wrong import this means you have older pip than version 10.0, so either use simply `import pip` or update pip first.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: It might has something to do with the python interpreter, but I still don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: It's simply `import pip`, not `import pip._internal`. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373. Replacing `pip._internal` with `pip` should make this work.

Comment: @connectyourcharger since pip v10 it's pip._internal see: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4700

Comment: @Zydnar Depending on OP's version of pip, it may vary.

Comment: I entered your first piece of code and this is the output I get: ['pip', 'setuptools']
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. 

Weirdly enough though, when I try to update pip, through command promt, it states that I already have the latest version installed (Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\yassi\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (18.1))

Comment: This says, package instalation is broken. If you have only `['pip', 'setuptools']` installed you don't even loose much time by reinstalling your python enviroment. And by reinstall I mean remove previous installation.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. After trying it multiple times, I came across this solution and it worked.

Basically, you need to create an interpreter which points to kivy folder('kivy_venv' folder which was created using steps similar to this installation link: [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#start-a-kivy-application](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#start-a-kivy-application)

1. Open **Pycharm**
2. Click **'File'** tab in upper left corner
3. click on **'Settings'**
4. click on **'Project:test'**
5. click **'Python Interpreter'**
6. click on **'Settings symbol'** (wheel shaped) next to **'Python Interpreter'**
7. click on **'show all'**
8. click on **'+'** plus symbol
9. Set **'Location'** to the folder where **'PycharmProject'** folder is situated.(To find out PycharmProject folder location, click on **File->Open->ProjectName** ) (I would recommend you to create a new folder in PycharmProject say **'kivyProject1'**) In my case, Location is **C:\Users\Shraddha\PycharmProjects\kivyProject1**
10. Set **'Interpreter'** to the folder where kivy was installed.(If you installed kivy using steps at [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#start-a-kivy-application](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#start-a-kivy-application) ,  you will have **'kivy_venv'** folder. Copy the complete address of **'kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe'** and paste at **'Interpreter'** ) In my case, **Interpreter is C:\Users\Shraddha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe**
11. Click on **'Edit'** (a pencil shaped symbol at right side) and set name **Name: Python 3.7 (kivyenv1)** Keep **Location** as it was.In my case **Location is C:\Users\Shraddha\PycharmProjects\kivyProject1\Scripts\python.exe**
12. Click **OK**. Then **OK**.  Now you are out of **'Settings'**.
13. Create new python program **filename.py** to check if **kivy** is imported. For that, Click **File->Create new project** and ensure its location is **C:\Users\Shraddha\PycharmProjects\kivyProject1\filename.py**
14. In **filename.py**, type ***import kivy*** and run by clicking on **PLAY** button. You must get logs as : ***succesfully imported kivy***

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Am using **windows 10** in VS code and **below is a solution that works**:

The solution was to run this:

```
python -m pip install kivy==2.0.0rc1
```

I don't know why this works, but the website instruction appears to use an older version:
`python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1` which fails.

You can test by running a `kivyTest.py` file with one line of code (below):

```
import kivy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
1) Open an Anaconda command prompt.
2) Type `code`, and then press enter.
3) Now open your file and run your code in "this" VScode.

**More explanation:**
I was facing the same problem (installed kivy by running `conda install kivy -c conda-forge` in an Anaconda command prompt), and I couldn't import `kivy`  in VScode that is opened normally and not from the Anaconda environment (got the `ImportError: No module named 'kivy'` error), but then I opened VScode from Anaconda Navigator, and run the same code and this time I didn't get any error. Then I searched if it was possible to open VScode from Anaconda command prompt (like when you want to open an IPython notebook with `jupyer notebook`), because the prompt loads much faster than the navigator. And found out it is done by typing `code` and pressing enter.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

if you installed it just restart your computer. I faced same problem I search on many sites
I don't get solution than shutdown pc next day I restart it its working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with virtualenv in VS Code. The issue was that I should select Python interpreter from bin in virtualenv.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error and no solution that mentioned here worked for it!
It happen because of virtual environment and after activating it , everything goes well!

Answer (score 0):

This was bugging me but I found the solution!

You need to change the interpreter to the python.exe in the Scripts folder for your virtual environment!

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnqnj.png)

[Add a new interpreter set to your virtual environment python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwiHg.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35319787)