# No module found for Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, importerror

Hello I know this question has been asked multiple times , but I am still having problem , I have tried all the solution in the other threads but it isn't working for me.

I have error when I run my python file

```
"No module named Kivy "
```

I have also set the path of the kivy correctly . Still the error persist .

Things I have tried :

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named kivy.app in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310545/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-kivy-app-in-python)

[Trying to run KIVY, for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113270/trying-to-run-kivy-for-the-first-time)

[No module named 'Kivy' even though I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686801/no-module-named-kivy-even-though-i-installed-it)

My code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

Comment: do you have multiple version of python installed on your device... last time i checked, kivy works only for python <= 3.7.5

Comment: I have Python version 3.8.2 , U think maybe thats what causing the error?  And also note that i am using acaconda , does it make any difference ?

Comment: @PratikAgarwal That is causing the issue then.

Answer (score 1):

This might be Issue with the version of the python you are using. Try this command :-

```
 python --version
```

The result might be either **Python 2.X.XX** or **Python 3.X.XX**.

If the result is **Python 2.X.XX**, use this command to install ***kivy***

```
pip install kivy
         OR
python -m pip install kivy
```

Or if the result is **Python 3.X.XX**, use

```
pip3 install kivy 
       OR
python -m pip3 install kivy
```

> Note : You need to have ***pip*** or *pip3* install in your system.

Comment: Let me also add: Sometimes you need to do `python -m pip install kivy`, or `python -m pip3 install kivy`. It works for me all the time.

Comment: @10Rep Thanks for that additional knowledge. I have added that to may answer.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum version of python that kivy supports at this moment is python3.7 and i'll even recommend python3.6 instead